# parsing JSONArray with org.json disorder structure

Tags: android, json, loops, geojson, org.json

Hello all I want to ask how to parse getting JSONArray value with org.json ?

I have geojson data like this

```
{
"features": [
    {
  "geometry": {
    "coordinates": [
      112.732816,
      -7.246557
    ],
    "type": "Point"
  },
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "tinggi_tower": 80,
    "nm_type": "SST (4 kaki)",
    "site_id": "SBYPASTUR",
    "nama_site": "Pasar Turi Utara",
    "nm_kota": "Surabaya",
    "nm_site_type": "GF",
    "jml_tenant": 2
  }
}
],
"type": "FeatureCollection"
}
```

I want to getting langtitude and longtitude value than I'm trying parse with library org.json like this

```
limap = new ArrayList<Site_Map_Client>();
JSONArray arrfeatures = json.getJSONArray("features");
    for (int i = 0; i < arrfeatures.length(); i++) {
        Site_Map_Client modmap = new Site_Map_Client();
        JSONObject objfeatures = arrfeatures.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject objgeo = objfeatures.getJSONObject("geometry");
        JSONArray arrcoord = objgeo.getJSONArray("coordinates");
            //how to get longtitude and latitude value for this loop
            for (int j = 0; j < arrcoord.length(); j++) {
                if(i == 0){
                    modmap.setLongtitude(arrcoord.getDouble(i));
                } else if (i == 1) {
                    modmap.setLatitude(arrcoord.getDouble(i));
                }
            }
            JSONObject objprop = objfeatures.getJSONObject("properties");
            modmap.setSiteid(objprop.getString("site_id"));
            modmap.setNmsite(objprop.getString("nama_site"));
            modmap.setTipetower(objprop.getString("nm_type"));
            modmap.setTipesite(objprop.getString("nm_site_type"));
            modmap.setTinggitower(objprop.getDouble("tinggi_tower"));
            modmap.setKota(objprop.getString("nm_kota"));
            modmap.setJmtenant(objprop.getInt("jml_tenant"));

            limap.add(modmap);
        }
```

The problem is why longtitude and langtitude structure was disordered and I'm getting wrong coordinate?
any idea for iterate JsonArray for this case study ?

Sorry for my bad english, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I'm sorry, I'm wrong looking the looping

the iterate must be like this

```
for (int j = 0; j < arrcoord.length(); j++) {
            if(j == 0){
                modmap.setLongtitude(arrcoord.getDouble(j));
            } else if (j == 1) {
                modmap.setLatitude(arrcoord.getDouble(j));
            }
        }
```

and was solved now

Answer (score 0):

Your inner for loop should look like this

```
for (int j = 0; j < arrcoord.length(); j++) {
      if(j == 0){
         modmap.setLongtitude(arrcoord.getDouble(i));
      } else if (j == 1) {
         modmap.setLatitude(arrcoord.getDouble(i));
      }
}
```

Use `j` variable instead of `i` in if statement.